# pass String value to a Double quotes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

hi i am using Javascript Dynamic Textbox for my application now want to get the value too my DB.

Please look in this code, I am Using HTML input for dynamic textbox

```
    string k = HiddenField1.Value;
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(k);

    for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
    {



        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string name = "txtName" + j.ToString();

            string Namevalue = Page.Request.Form["\"name\""].ToString();

            string PPT = "txtPPT" + j.ToString();
            string PPTvalue = Page.Request.Form["PPT"].ToString();

            string Age = "NA";
```

i want to pass the value name `toPage.Request.Form["\"name\""].ToString();`

Please help I am new to .net

Comment: Try this : `Page.Request.Form[@"\name\"].ToString();`

Comment: @bios I'd rather say use `Page.Request.Form[name].ToString();` as **name** is a variable of type **string**.

Comment: I got the solution it will come as Page.Request.Form[@name].ToString(); Thanks a lot for all your support :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need use

```
string Namevalue = Page.Request.Form[name].ToString();
```

instead of

```
string Namevalue = Page.Request.Form["\"name\""].ToString();
```

and same with `PPT`

```
string PPTvalue = Page.Request.Form[PPT].ToString();
```

instead of

```
string PPTvalue = Page.Request.Form["PPT"].ToString();
```

because your string variables `name` and `PPT` contains value what you need

Comment: Sorry, thought you'd made that mistake, my bad! ;) +1, You're answer is indeed correct.

Comment: I got the solution it will come as Page.Request.Form[@name].ToString(); Thanks a lot for all your support :)